# postgresql binay path missing in preferences

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-16

I recentrly added the newest version of postgres 16, so I wanted to do a backup from my older DB with dump, but in preferences when I try to select the binary path for the new one I don't see it

Servers:

[image]

Preferences - Binary path:

[image]

I supposed that I should see the Database Server 16

Comment: Why don't you "Select binary path" like the GUI suggests?

Comment: 1) How did you install Postgres 16? 2) Are you sure you don't just need to scroll down some more to get the 16 settings?

Comment: 1) I installed it directly from the webpage, downloaded the installer for windows for the 16 version, 2) No, I double check and even restarted my computer after installation